# jQuery DataTable TypeError: Cannot set property 'destroy' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables

```
<script>
  $('#messagesTable').DataTable({});
</script>

<table id="messagesTable" datatable="ng" class="table table-sm" style="color:black">
  <!--some code-->
</table>
```

This is my code in HTML

and I have error in browser console:
`angular.js:11594 TypeError: Cannot set property 'destroy' of undefined`

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

DataTables requires a well formed table. It must contain `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#messagesTable').DataTable({});
});
```

```html
<table id="messagesTable" datatable="ng" class="table table-sm" style="color:black">
  <!--some code-->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col one</th>
      <th>col two</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>data one</td>
    <td>data two</td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```